# How to instantiate an array object of type int and populate it in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create an array object of type int to populate it with randomly generated integers. After creating the object, it is marked as undefined by my compiler.
Example

```
  int *randomArrray = new int [numOfElements];
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++)
    {
        randomdArray[i] = getRandoms(numOfElements, upperBound, lowerBound);
    }
```

the second randomArray is the one marked as undefined in my compiler. It is supposed to be populated by random integers. I am following this approach since I was able to do a similar code snippet that worked and looks like this.

```
double *setValuesInArray = new double [valuesInArray];
    for(int i = 0; i < valuesInArray; i++){
        setValuesInArray[i] = getInputs();
    }
```

Am I forgetting to do something this time that I did last time? I can't see it.

Comment: You have a typo! Arrr instead of Arr. This is a bad question.

Comment: Your array names also seem to be `random` like those `random` numbers you are adding to it.

Comment: Guys, let's not troll him. Maybe he's a beginner and hasn't experienced yet those hours wasted on an extra `;` bug.

Comment: No problems =-)
I'll take criticism and trolling as long as it leads to the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have `randomdArray[i]` with an extra `d` in front of `A` and one less `r` (in declaration you have `randomArrray` with 3 `r`s)

Comment: Thanks, I can't vote up because I need more reputation points ^_^

Comment: No problem. Just be careful with the code you write, ensure that every character you write is valid. Some of the worst to solve bugs are caused by a forgotten/extra `*` or `;`